# Are finished threads always automatically removed from Linux cgroup tasks file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

Perhaps, the logics may be found somewhere in Linux kernel source code(?) Are finished threads always automatically removed from a cgroup `tasks` file? I see that they are removed on practice. But is there any guarantee for Linux on that?

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ? Why do you need to know this? Or perhaps the `c` and `c++` tags are offtopic, and you can tag `posix` ?

Comment: For example, to know if I should remove them manually. Also, I am particularly interested in Linux.

Comment: I removed the C and C++ tags as this seems to be a general question and not related to a specific programming language. If you have a narrower question about a piece of code you are writing you can add a [mre] and the relevant language tag.

Comment: If you're talking about files in /proc, /sys, or sometimes /dev, these aren't real filesystems, the files don't actually exist on disk or anywhere. They're an API to the kernel that can be accessed using the filesystem API (open/read/write/readdir), but the "files"/"folders" don't actually exist on storage. When you open the file for reading/writing, the virtual filesystem driver translates those calls to function calls inside the kernel to read/modify the kernel state. So yes, the "files" are always up to date because they are generated directly from the kernel state.